# Euclids Method to calculate GCD

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        int a1 = b;
        int b1 = a % b;
        GCD(a1, b1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

}

Why does this implementation of Euclid's Algo (in Java) always return 1.? How do I get it to return the right answer?

Comment: Looks like you mean to have `return GCD(a1, b1);`

Comment: Sorry ddi not get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return statement. You made the recursive call, but did not use the value.

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        int a1 = b;
        int b1 = a % b;
        // return here
        return GCD(a1, b1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Although, you can write it succinctly like this:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Or in one line:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply missed a `return`, so you code just runs to the end and returns with 1.

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        int a1 = b;
        int b1 = a % b;
        return GCD(a1, b1);
    }
    return 1;
}
}
```